# What is the meaning of "One giving way for another" in this text?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I am reading a book it says:

Every time I think about Deborah, it baffles me how she successfully managed her multi role in life as a woman without one giving way for another.

What is the meaning of "One giving way for another"?

Comment: Out of context it appears to be quite a badly written sentence. Were two roles defined in the previous text? (inference: having both a family and a career?) In which case "the one" and "the other" would refer to the two roles interchangeably.

Comment: @marktristan Maybe it defined in following text. the following is:  As   a wife, mother-in-Israel,jusge,warrior,prophetess etc.

Comment: @hgs You should have made it clear that you were referring to the biblical "Deborah" mentioned in the Book of Judges. "Deborah" is a common first name for girls and thus, your example is poor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is expressing surprise that Deborah can successfully carry out all her different roles at the same time.

Deborah's "multi role" does not indicate how many roles she has, but does show that she has at least two different roles. "One giving way for another" could be expanded to "one *role* giving way for another *role*" and means "**one role being neglected or abandoned in order to allow another role to be prioritized**".